# New Asp.Net core project not getting build with docker command

Tags: c#, docker

I created new Asp.net core project in VS2017, and selected docker support for linux. the docker file looks like below

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApp2/WebApp2.csproj", "WebApp2/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApp2/WebApp2.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApp2"
RUN dotnet build "WebApp2.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApp2.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApp2.dll"]
```

When i run the below docker build command, I'm getting an error.

`docker buid -t mylogin/dotnetcoreapp1 .`

#### Error Message

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.125MB
Step 1/16 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
 ---> 651a14e0b96b
Step 2/16 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in 929f4fdb28f2
Removing intermediate container 929f4fdb28f2
 ---> 54cdd8399e5b
Step 3/16 : EXPOSE 80
 ---> Running in 844cfb6d1638
Removing intermediate container 844cfb6d1638
 ---> b15703d4c881
Step 4/16 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
 ---> 1f3b89fbfa01
Step 5/16 : WORKDIR /src
 ---> Running in 07375b9916a3
Removing intermediate container 07375b9916a3
 ---> dc4227c9d5ec
Step 6/16 : COPY ["WebApp2.csproj", ""]
 ---> 1cd0239157a4
Step 7/16 : RUN dotnet restore "/WebApp2.csproj"
 ---> Running in 73fad81058fd
MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch.
Switch: /WebApp2.csproj
    
For switch syntax, type "MSBuild /help"
The command 'cmd /S /C dotnet restore "/WebApp2.csproj"' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: Try using 2.2, I had the same problem with 2.1 and is solved with 2.2

Comment: Tried updating 2.1 to 2.2 for boh sdk and dotnetcore images, but no luck.Getting the same error

Comment: Did you create new project with 2.2, with the Dockerfile from the template? I remember the old Dockerfile had wrong path.

Comment: And remember to update your Windows image to build too. As for me, I use `microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-1803` and `microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk-nanoserver-1803`. Please try with those.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, Just **move** the dockerfile one level up
for example your current csproj path is
c:\projects\MySolutionFolder\MyProj\MyProj.csproj (Where docker file is here as well)
Move the docker file to be in **"c:\projects\MySolutionFolder\"**

I hop it helps you.